# Why does createStore work but configureStore doesn't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am creating a simple counter app using `react` and `redux`.

The following is the `counterSlice.js` file.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState: { count: 0 },
  reducers: {
    changeValueBy(state, action) {
      const value = action.payload;
      state["count"] = state["count"] + value;
    }
  }
});

export const { changeValueBy } = counterSlice.actions;

export const selectCount = (state) => state.count;

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

The following is the `app/store.js` file:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import counterReducer from "../features/counter/counterSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer
  }
});
```

The following is the `index.js` file:

```
import App from "./App";
import store from "./app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux"

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

With this setup, the code doesn't work.
(Entire code is in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/counter-app-using-react-and-redux-configurestore-4td5nk?file=/src/index.js:232-388))

But with following setup, the `store` works.

The `App.js` file:

```
import { Counter } from "./features/counter/Counter";
import "./App.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import counterSlice from "./features/counter/counterSlice";

const store = createStore(counterSlice);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Counter />
        </Provider>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The entire code is in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/counter-app-using-react-and-redux-createstore-9cq7pz).

I would like to use `configureStore` form the `@reduxjs/toolkit` package and not the outdated `createStore` from `redux` package.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer
  }
});
```

is equivalent to

```js
const store = createStore(combineReducers: {
  counter: counterSlice
});
```

which means that the data from `counterSlice` will be found at `state.counter`.

Your old code does `createStore(counterSlice)`, which means that the data from `counterSlice` will be found at `state`.

So, both work, but you will have to select the data from different places depending on what you do.

Your selector

```js
export const selectCount = (state) => state.count;
```

would have to be

```js
export const selectCount = (state) => state.counter.count;
```

instead.